# Moving stored procedure with Views from local server to Azure. Trying to move minimal amount of data

Tags: azure, view, ssis

I have a stored procedure on local server. It has many views that are over one level deep. So now I have to move that stored procedure to work on the Azure server. I'm trying to use extended tables for the Views sources. But is there some way to use SSIS to update the Views values in the final levels? Or does each level in the view have to run it's course till it hits the final values. I was considering just making the final View a table and updating it with SSIS and leaving it at that. And not even bothering with the other views in it's layer by running the View on the local server. And using SSIS to move the final Views data.

So what is the least amount of resistance to get about tables and a 7 Views about 3 levels deep into Azure?

When I tried to directly insert Values in the Views I got error. "DML Operations are not supported with external tables"

Tried using SSIS to just move the data to Azure.